# Scala Exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am learning Scala programming to write driver program for word count in Apache Spark .I am using Windows 7 and Latest Spark version 2.2.0. While executing the program getting below mentioned error.

How to fix and get result ?

### SBT

> ```
> name := "sample"
>
> version := "0.1"
>
> scalaVersion := "2.12.3"
>
> val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"
>
> libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
>   "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % sparkVersion,
>   "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % sparkVersion,
>   "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % sparkVersion
>
> )
> ```

### Driver Program

```
package com.demo.file

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object Reader {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Welcome to Reader.")
    val filePath = "C:\\notes.txt"
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Simple app").config("spark.master", "local")getOrCreate();
    val fileData = spark.read.textFile(filePath).cache()
    val count_a = fileData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    val count_b = fileData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()

    println(s" count of A $count_a and count of B $count_b")
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

> ### Error
>
> ```
> Welcome to Reader.
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$DeprecatedConfig.<init>(SparkConf.scala:723)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<init>(SparkConf.scala:571)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<clinit>(SparkConf.scala)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:92)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:81)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:905)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:905)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.$anonfun$foreach$1(HashMap.scala:138)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry$(HashTable.scala:229)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:138)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:905)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:901)
>   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:901)
>   at com.demo.file.Reader$.main(Reader.scala:11)
>   at com.demo.file.Reader.main(Reader.scala)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>   ... 18 more
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark 2.2.0 is built and distributed to work with Scala 2.11 by default. To write applications in Scala, you will need to use a compatible Scala version (e.g. 2.11.X). And your scala version is 2.12.X. That's why it is throwing exception.

Comment: I have downloaded Spark version 2.11.11 and configured SPARK_HOME. Added in Intellij settings. File -> Project Structure -> Libraries  and Global Libraries . ( after that I faced compiler lib problem. uninstalled Scala plugin and then reinstall ) . changed spark version in sbt file scalaVersion := "2.11.11" restart the IDE . it works fine.